# Setting properties from CSV file using eval (Python)

Tags: python

I have CSV files that contain numerous values that I want to reference. I wanted to parse them succinctly using `eval`. Here's what I tried:

```
line = fileHandle.readline()
while line != "":
  if line != "\n":
    parameter = line.split(',')[0]
    value = line.split(',')[2].replace("\n", "")
    eval("%s = \"%s\"" % (parameter, value))
    print(parameter + " = " + eval(parameter)) # a quick test
  line = fileHandle.readline()
```

What I get is:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 73, in ?
  File "<string>", line 70, in createJMSProviders
  File "<string>", line 49, in createJMSProviderFromFile
  File "<string>", line 1
    externalProviderURL="tibjmsnaming://..."
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I reads to me like it is not possible to `eval("externalProviderURL=\"tibjmsnaming://...\"")`. What is wrong with this statement?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `csv` module? http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: I am a python newbie. Let me see if that module is supported in my environment (WAS 6). Question still stands though, academically.

Comment: You almost certainly want a dictionary instead of creating variables in the global scope using `eval`. The `csv` module has a very useful `DictReader` class. http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader Also, the `csv` module has been in the Python standard library since version 2.3.

Comment: @Wilduck: Please post an answer showing how this would work.

Comment: Unless you _really_ know what you're doing, `eval` is almost always the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @S.Lott As far as I understand what the OP is trying to achieve, it would involve building a new dictionary with keys equal to what is in the first column and values equal to what is in the third column (it seems a normal csv reader would work just fine here). If the OP would like this, I could give it a shot, but it seems that mathematical.coffee has better answered the question as asked.

Comment: @Wilduck: Answering the literal question (when it's misguided) isn't being helpful.  Providing advice that fixes the misguided part of the question is good.  It's okay to answer the question they **should** have asked.

Comment: @S.Lott I agree. Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval()` is for evaluation Python *expressions*, and assignment (`a = 1`) is a *statement*.
You'll want `exec()`.

```
>>> exec("externalProviderURL=\"tibjmsnaming://...\"")
>>> externalProviderURL
'tibjmsnaming://...'
```

(FYI, to use `eval()` you'd have to do `externalProviderURL=eval("\"tibjmsnaming://...\"")`, but it looks like your situation is more suited to `exec`).

Comment: Unless you _really_ know what you're doing, `exec` is almost always the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

As per S.Lott's suggestion, here is how I would solve this issue. I might be simplifying a little bit. If so, I apologize, but I haven't seen your data.

```
import csv
my_dict = {}
with open('my/data.csv') as f:
    my_reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in my_reader:
        my_dict[row[0]] = row[2]
```

As you can see, there are a number of differences from your code here. First of all, I'm using Python's [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), which is a good habit to get into when working with files. Second, I'm using python's [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module to create a reader object, which you can iterate over in a `for` loop. This is significantly more pythonic than using a `while` loop. Finally, and probably most relevantly, I'm adding these values to a dictionary, rather than trying to plop them into variables in the global scope. To access these parameters, you can simply do the following:

```
my_dict['externalProviderURL']
```

However, you get a lot more than this. Storing your values in an actual data structure will allow you use all of it's [built in methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). For example, you can go back and iterate over it's keys and values

```
for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
    print key 
    print value
```

Pythonic code often involves a significant use of dictionaries. They're finely tuned for performance, and are made particularly useful since most anything can be stored as a value in the dictionary (lists, other dictionaries, functions, classes etc.)

Comment: Thanks Wilduck. I got burnt by exec after added a value to the CSV file that was not alphanumeric. e.g. 'this-that.1.2.3'.  So I tried to import the csv module and use your approach, but this module is not available to me in WebSphere 6. Not sure if I manually add it to my environment. How might I do that? Also the `with` syntax didn't seem to work. I'm sure I have a very old version.

Comment: I know little to nothing about IBM WebSphere. However, it looks like you're actually working with Jython 2.1 (http://wiki.python.org/jython/WebSphere). If this is the case, you might start looking for java libraries to work with csv files.